# differences between `--table` and `--create` options in laravel5 make:migration

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-5

I don't know what differences between `php artisan make:migration --table` and  `php artisan make:migration --create` options?!I was completely confused :( 
Are there any differences?
When should I use `--table` option or `--create` option?
[`laravel` says that :](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations)

> The `--table` and `--create` options may also be used to indicate the
>   name of the table, and whether the migration will be creating a new
>   table

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that I find the answer.To **create a new database table**, the `Schema::create` method is used (`--create` option) and to **update an existing table**, we can use the `Schema::table` method (`--table` option).

Comment: Shouldn't be better to call --update instead of --table to update migration table? It is also a bit confusing to me and on Laravel site it doesn't tell relevant information about both options.

Answer (score 1):

**--create** means to create;
**--table** means to alter an (existing) table;

But I do agree that this can cause a lot of confusion...to use a verb and a noun on the same level...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you were a new visitor to this question, and you read the accepted answer (from 3 years ago), do you think that your personal answer would be beneficial? What you've stated is a 'comment' which you can add to questions and answers once you have 50+ reputation.

Comment: I am new here. Thanks for your guidance.